# Recover deleted remote branch on bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I accidentally deleted the release branch by clicking three dots in front of the branch row and clicking the delete button. I need to recover it.

Comment: Do you have a local copy of it? Then you can just create a new branch and push it.
Here are suggestions from [bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-restore-a-deleted-branch-765757540.html)

Answer (score 0):

*(My assumption is that you don't have the branch in your local repo any more. If you **do**, just push it again to recreate it, of course. If not, follow on.)*

An easy two-steps way to recreate the branch is :

**1** -> look for the last PR *from* that branch, get on the commits tab to display the PR's commits, then copy the most recent one's hash (at the top).

**2** -> from your local repo :

```
$ git checkout -b <branchName> <hashYouCopied>
$ git push -u
```

First command will recreate it in your repo, second one will push it back to the remote.

---

*Worth noting though : this is mostly a restore process for feature branches, and it might not be suited for release branches, depending on your workflow. In some cases, release branches are not merged into anything through PRs, and this could also miss recent commits if people have push permissions on the branch. So be sure to adapt it to your needs.*